# Get URL from visibile element and add link to another element?

Tags: jquery, select, element, href, visible

I use a slideshow and try to get the link from an image and add this link to title and descripion.

The problem with this slideshow is, that it preloads all images and changes the visibility status from hidden to visible.

I would like to get the URL only from the visible image.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rgslideshow-4574" class="rgslideshow">
<a href="fuer-patienten">
<a href="fuer-patienten/unser-team">
<img class="rgssimg" width="715" height="361" border="0" title="Dies ist eine Beschreibung zu Bild 2 " alt="Dies ist eine Beschreibung zu Bild 2" src="uploads/tx_rgslideshow/test2.jpg" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
</a>
<a href="fuer-patienten/patienteninformationen">
<img class="rgssimg" width="715" height="361" border="0" title="Dies ist eine Beschreibung zu Bild 3 " alt="Dies ist eine Beschreibung zu Bild 3" src="uploads/tx_rgslideshow/test3.jpg" style="display: block; visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
</a>
</div>
```

**This is what I tried with jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var getUrlFromHREF = $('#rgslideshow-4574 a ').attr('href');

    alert(getUrlFromHREF);

    $('.rgstitle, .rgsdescription').click(function(event) {
        window.open(getUrlFromHREF, '_self');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I looked for `rgslideshow` but it seems to be really old and no longer in development.

Comment: Yes, its an old extension for TYPO3.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not using the opacity to show/hide the pictures, this should work (

```
$('.rgstitle, .rgsdescription').click(function(event) {
    window.open($('#rgslideshow-4574 a:visible').attr('href'), '_self');
    return false;
});
```

EDIT: You shouldn't define the link when you load the document, but only when you click, as you are interested in the link of the current visible image.

Comment: You'd have to check with Firebug if it's the link or the image which is hidden. In that last case, solution from Xander is better

Comment: Your code is working - you just forgot the parent():      ----   $('.rgstitle, .rgsdescription').click(function(event) { 
    window.open($('#rgslideshow-4574 a img:visible').parent().attr('href'), '_self'); 
    return false; 
});

Comment: I didn't forget, it's because I thought the link was the hidden element... Feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var getUrlFromHREF = $('#rgslideshow-4574 a img').filter(':visible').parent().attr('href');
```

You'll get a slight boost in performance using this method over jQuery's [custom :visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Update: Just noticed your HTML is invalid. The first anchor is not closed.

Comment: Now I get the first link, but the second slide still shows the first link. I checked the document and the a-tag is closed: http://www.thermewienmed.at/index.php?id=388

Comment: Now I get the first link, but the second slide still shows the first link. ----- the code from Nabab is working - he just forgot the parent tag --- anyway thank you!